# UnKnownHostException in Http Post of Android Application

Tags: android

In Http Post, the values are not send to server. I got **unknownhostexception** at following line.`HttpResponse rs=httpclient.execute(httppost);`

**http Coding:**

```
          HttpClient httpclient=new DefaultHttpClient();

          HttpPost httppost=new HttpPost("http://www.mysite.com/fasttrack/androidapps.php");


          httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(data));

          appendLog("7)Value Encoded to url successfully");


      HttpResponse rs=httpclient.execute(httppost); // unknownhostexception got
```

I added     `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`  in Manifestfile also...

Note : this codings works fine before I added log file codings...

**my Log File coding is below:**

```
public void appendLog(String text)
        {      
            //File logFile = new File("alog.txt");
           File logFile = new File("sdcard/alog.file");
           if (!logFile.exists())
           {
              try
              {
                 logFile.createNewFile();
              } 
              catch (IOException e)
              {
                 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                 e.printStackTrace();
              }
           }
           try
           {
              //BufferedWriter for performance, true to set append to file flag
              BufferedWriter buf = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(logFile, true)); 
              buf.append(text);
              buf.newLine();
              buf.close();
           }
           catch (IOException e)
           {
              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
              e.printStackTrace();
           }
        }
```

Comment: please close the emulator and clean project then run again.. waiting your feedback

Comment: just check with your browser first if internet is working or not?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the android emulator's browser stops working. So, try to restart your emulator from cmd like this,

```
run->cmd->your_sdk_path->tools->emulator -avd avd_name -dns-server 8.8.8.8
```